# Shell Scripting----Correction needed

Tags: shell, scripting

I need a correction in my shell syntax (given below)

```
cat $dfn | gawk
'{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 1)
 {printf "%f\t", ((($i / $tag) / $bn ) */ 1000000000);}
 printf "\n"}'>fn
```

where `$dfn` is the file name `$tag` and `$bn` hold a value. and `fn` is the the file where output is being directed.

Note: what this line does, it takes a file name ( which is of n by m dimension and contains a value in each cell) divides each value in the cell by the value in `$tag` variable answer of this is divided again by the value in `$bn` and finally after all division operations are performed the value is multiplied by 1 billion.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the matter in this script? Can you provide *sample* values for the file pointed by `$dfn` and for `$tag` and `$bn`?

Comment: $dfn is a tab delimited file containing values and is of the order n by m. $ tag = 12000000 and $bn = 60000000000

Comment: I wanted to have some values, to be able to run tests localy. But it looks like I won't need anymore.

Comment: In addition to other comments, you don't need the `cat` command: `gawk '...' < $dfn > fn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shuld change the /* to * when you mutiply the value by 1 Billion.

Answer (score 3):

The variables `$tag` and `$bn` are referring to fields in the lines. I'm assuming you actually want them to be environment variables. Pass them as variables to awk:

```
cat $dfn | 
    gawk -v tag="$tag" -v bn="$bn" '{
      for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 1) {
        printf "%f\t", ((($i / tag) / bn ) * 1000000000)
      }
      printf "\n"
    }'>fn
```

Edit: Also fix the multiplication as indicated by Raghuram.

Comment: @Angelo You need to change the multiplication, too.